# Guest Checkout for Paypal Subscriptions

Tags: wordpress, paypal, subscription

We are using Simple Membership Plugin on WP to have subscription levels for our users.  When people go to checkout on Paypal if they don't have a PayPal account it makes it so they need to set up a Paypal account to continue.

Our Business account has PayPal Account Optional turned on and we are wondering if there is a way to have guest checkout for subscription buttons for Paypal?

Answer (score 2):

With subscriptions guest checkout is not available.  The user would have to create a PayPal account.

If you don't want this you'll need to upgrade to Payments Pro w/ Recurring Billing.

Comment: thanks.   My client didn't want to pay for payments pro so as a workaround we made the subscriptions payments and they're just going to email them when their membership needs renewed.   
Not the best UX practice I tried to tell them but it was a workaround.

Comment: That seems like a different issue than you originally mentioned.  For that you should use IPN.  You can automate tasks based on transaction types like new profiles being created, payments being made against profiles, profiles getting canceled, expiring, etc.

Comment: Sorry I mispoke.   The workaround was to make them buy a year rather than subscribe since buys on Paypal allows guest checkouts and they wanted to just manage the rebuys per year.   They're a limited # of memberships organizations so they decided to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Guest checkout now appears to be available for PayPal subscriptions in the US and Canada.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/#guest-user-flow-using-a-debit-or-credit-card